# Сохранение цен в логах

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, интернет-магазин, ecommerce

Есть таблица товаров (`Goods`). У каждого товара есть цена. При создании заказа (`Order`) к нему прикрепляются товары с помощью дополнительной таблицы `Goods__Order`. При этом после заказа цены товаров в заказе не должны меняться, даже если они изменились в таблице Goods.

Один из вариантов - сохранять цену в таблицу `Goods__Order`. Но количество полей, которые не должны меняться, возможно, станет больше, и поэтому не хочется их все переносить в эту таблицу + вариант не очень универсальный.

Второй вариант, как мне кажется, можно логировать изменения в таблице `Goods` в таблицу `Goods_audit`, которая будет содержать изменения полей + номер версии (revision number). Это доступно через Hibernate Envers. Но тогда в таблицу `Goods_Order` нужно будет вносить id товара + номер версии + я не нашел примеров, что так делают.

Какой вариант будет лучше? Учитывая, огромное количество интернет-магазинов, наверное уже есть более-менее известное решение для этого. Да и во вариантах на php никакого Hibernate Envers нет.

Comment: Лучше будет если сначала изучить отработанный веками бухгалтерский учёт. И делать всё как там сказано. Лучше вряд ли получится, а вот хуже почти наверняка. Цена и стоимость товара в заказе - это неотъемлимая часть заказа. Хотя бы что-то одно из них должно быть в заказе непременно.

Comment: Должна быть таблица версионности (Ваш второй пример) где хранится актуальная цена на нужную вам дату( период). При формировании Заказа вы выбираете данные с учётом даты заказа. Проще всего организовать через хранимую процедуру

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Заказ не является объектом бухгалтерского учета, это объект процессов логистики
  и взаимоотношения с клиентами. Однозначных рекомендаций по
  логистике и CRM не существует, правильная постановка таких процессов
  является ноухау организации.
- Пока заказ не оплачен, он является по сути предложением клиенту и
  объектом любой переоценки.
- В магазине могут действовать правила расчета цены
  отдельного товара для клиента с учетом скидок (иногда и надбавок) -
  скидка по промокоду, скидка за объем заказа (суммарный по всем
  товарным позициям заказа), персональная скидка клиента (например - за
  историю заказов, либо скидка отдельным категориям клиентов), и т.д.
- За время, когда заказ ожидает оплаты, может стартовать кампания по
  стимулированию спроса - на отдельные товары/группы начинает
  действовать значительная скидка, которая отменяет другие скидки
  (промокод, песональные и т.д.).
- После того, как заказ оплачен (тем более - если исполнен), все
  текущие условия - базовая цена, скидки, условия доставки и пр. -
  должны быть зафиксированы и не подлежать дальнейшим изменениям.
- В развитых eComm платформах типа Magento текущие цены ведутся в
  отдельных объектах - прайс-листах, могут настраиваться правила
  перерасчета цен (скажем, в зависимости от валютных котировок для импортных
  товаров), ведется история изменения прайс-листов.
- Правила перерасчета неоплаченных заказов также могут настраиваться.

Так должно быть, а реализуется ли это в конкретной eComm и как - зависит от платформы. Если сами пишете платформу - посоветуйтесь с отделом продаж :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. *Топорный вариант* В таблицу Order(заказ)пишите цену на момент заказа добавить поле price(цена).
2. Создать таблицу price_history[ид товара,номер ревизии,цена, дата и прочее если надо] и вносить каждое изменения цены туда. В таблице Goods хранится всего лишь ид ревизии цены.

Comment: Оба варианта я и расписал в вопросе. Вопрос в том, какой из них лучше и более расширяем. То есть меня интересуют плюсы и минусы.

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy На сколько я понимаю мелкие и средние интернет магазины не ведут историю цен. Да что там говорить и крупные так часто делают. Т. е. 1-вариант. могу сказать чтоб лавировать на крупном рынке сложно уследить за изменением цен у других на текущий момент при большом рынке, не то что еще и логировать и анализировать прошлые.